# Expected gain in a game

Tags: probability, expected-value

In a gambling, a man will win $\$10$ if he is managed to get 5 or 6 facing up in rolling a fair die, he will need to pay $\$5$ otherwise. If the man continues to play the game until he wins 3 times, what is his expected gain?

Here's my working:

{5 or 6}            =2/6=1/3

(1 or 2 or 3 or 4}  =4/6=2/3

Expected gain = (1/3) * $$10 + (2/3) * -$5 =  $0 for each round

Comment: Each roll can be seen as a trial with success probability $p=\frac{1}{3}$. First, we are interested in obtaining the distribution for the number of trials until the third success. Well, it's pretty easy to calculate. If the third win is obtained on roll number $N~$ ($N\geq 3$), we know that the monetary balance at that point is
$$
B = 3\cdot 10 - (N-3)\cdot 5
$$
Since $n$ is a random variable, so is $B$. Can you use the laws of expectation to calculate $\mathbb{E}[B]$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the negative binomial distribution (the law that counts how many trials are needed to get $r$ successes) you get that the average numbers of draws is

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{r}{\theta}=\frac{3}{\frac{1}{3}}=9$$

Thus the expected gain is

$$3\times \$10+6\times(-\$5)=\$0$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the solution!